# Adjusting PKG_CONFIG_PATH does not work

Tags: pkg-config

I am having problems with installing a package that depends on another package - `poppler-glib`. I have `poppler-glib` (newest version) installed with the prefix `/home/user/local/poppler-glib` with `*.pc` files present in `/home/user/local/poppler-glib/lib/pkgconfig`. I have added that path to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable (I am on `tcsh`):

```
setenv PKG_CONFIG_PATH /home/user/local/poppler-glib/lib/pkgconfig
```

Nevertheless, when I try to run the `./configure` script of the other package, I am getting the following error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (poppler-glib >= 0.5.4) were not met:

No package 'poppler-glib' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables POPPLERGLIB_CFLAGS
and POPPLERGLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Therefore, question: how can I adjust the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable to make it visible?

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? I am facing this issue when trying to install psf2svg , which requires poppler as its dependency.

Comment: I had a similar issue, then I found out the `pkgconfig` I was using was just a script that overrides `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and calls the real program. In my case, setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH_CUSTOM` worked.

Comment: @LHLaurini I wish that worked for me. How did you find out that `pkgconfig` is using a script? I might have to look into what's going on as well.

Comment: facing the same issue on Debian Bullseye. This is really annoying

Comment: @polynomial_donut It's not that `pkgconfig` was using a script, but it **was** a script. You can check that by opening the program in a text editor. EDIT: I think I had this problem with msys2.

Answer (score -8):

Just install poppler-glib by using the command:
sudo apt-get install libpoppler-glib-dev